# Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, String>>' to type '[MyVC.Objects]'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, searchbar

I am trying to use an textfield as search bar for my table view. So i added below code. Now its showing some error like

`Cannot assign value of type 'Array<Dictionary<String, String>>' to type '[MyVC.Objects]'`

```
var objectArray = [Objects]()
var SearchedobjectArray = [Objects]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 SearchedobjectArray = objectArray

}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
    {
        if string.isEmpty
        {
            search = String(search.characters.dropLast())
        }
        else
        {
            search=textField.text!+string
        }

        print(search)
        let predicate=NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] %@", search)
        let arr=(objectArray as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate)

        if arr.count > 0
        {
            SearchedobjectArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
            SearchedobjectArray = arr as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>
        }
        else
        {
            SearchedobjectArray=objectArray
        }
        looTable.reloadData()
        return true
    }
```

Error is here :

`SearchedobjectArray = arr as! Array<Dictionary<String,String>>`I know that, i am not uses as `Array<Dictionary<String,String>`. But here how can i append like my onject i am not sure.

Any help on that ?

Comment: I am not sure what's strange cast are you attempting but the thing you are trying to do can be implemented using `SearchedobjectArray = objectArray.filter { $0.name.range(of: search, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }`. There is no need for `NSPredicate`, `NSArray` or if-else.

Comment: but my `objectArray` contains looName, id only... So if type any name contains  looName..it have to display in table view

Answer (score 0):

Fast fix:

```
SearchedobjectArray = arr as! [Objects]
```

Your array is not composed from dictionaries.

Real fix:

Forget `NSArray` and `NSPredicate` and use swift filtering:

```
SearchedobjectArray = objectArray.filter {
    $0.name.range(of: search, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
}

if SearchedobjectArray.isEmpty {
    SearchedobjectArray = objectArray
}
```